# Erro na consulta no MySQL utilizando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Vocês poderiam me explicar o porque do código PHP não executar o código da variável (esse código é uma query) na parte do ELSE.

Quando o IF (o IFcontém complementos de uma query que será executada no mysqli) não é executado, automaticamente ele entra no else (que também contém complementos de uma query que será executada no mysqli). Só que a variável do ELSE não é preenchida ou por algum motivo não é executada. A do IF acontece normalmente.

Sendo que coloquei uma variável de teste dentro do IF e do ELSE, e quando o IF não é executado, e a exibo a variável do ELSE, consta que a variável do ELSE foi preenchida.

VocÊs poderiam me ajudar ?

```js
//CÓDIGO PARA PREENCHIMENTO DA LISTA COM OS DADOS DA PESQUISA 
 
 $('#formulario-consulta').submit(function(e)
 {   
  e.preventDefault();
  var formulario = $(this);
  var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario);
 
 });
  
  function inserirFormulario(dados)
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
   //dataType: "json",
   type:"POST",
   data:dados.serialize(),
   url:"interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
   async:false
   
  }).done(function(data)
  {
   
   var atividades = "";
   
   $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor)
   {  


    

   
    atividades += '<tr id="'+ valor.codigo +'">';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.COD + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_VENCIMENTO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_INICIO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_FIM + '</td>';
    //atividades += '<td><button class="btn-warning" value="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    
    
    if(valor.STATUS == "INICIADO")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: ForestGreen; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
    
    else if(valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: DodgerBlue; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
       
    else if(valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: RoyalBlue; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
    
    else if(valor.STATUS == "VENCIDO")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: Red; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
    
    else if(valor.STATUS == "PENDENTE")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: DarkOrange; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
    
    else if(valor.STATUS == "INICIADO_VENCIDO")
    {
     atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: SeaGreen; color:white; font-weight: bold" value="'+ valor.codigo +'" id="' + valor.STATUS +'">'+ valor.STATUS +'</button></td>';
    }
    
    
    //atividades += '<td><button class="btn-secondary" id="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    atividades += '</tr>';
   });
   
   $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
    <!-- INÍCIO DA DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="pesquisa">
    
     <form id="formulario-consulta"> <!-- FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
      <div class="form-inline">   
      
        <div class="row">
        
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="botao-resumo" style="margin-top: 0">Resumo por Status</button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <select name="prioridade" id="prioridade" class="input-sm form-control">
             <option  value="Todos" selected>TODOS</option>
             <option  value="Comum">COMUM</option>
             <option  value="Extra">EXTRA</option>
             <option  value="Urgente">URGENTE</option>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por data de:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <select name="data" id="data" class="input-sm form-control">
             <option  value="inicio">INÍCIO</option>
             <option  value="finalizacao">FINALIZAÇÃO</option>
             <option  value="vencimento" selected>VENCIMENTO</option>
            </select>
           </div>
                                  
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por período:</h5>
           De: <input type="date" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
           Até: <input type="date" name="dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
                                        
          </div> 
         </div>
        </div>

       
       <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          
         <div class="">
         
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>COD</h5>
            <select  name="cod" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_cod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_cod))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Empresa</h5>
            <select name="empresas" id="empresas" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 100%">
            <option></option>
             <?php
             while($linha_empresas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_empresas))
             {
             ?> 
              <option value="<?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]; ?> "> 
               <?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]; ?>
              </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
           
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Tributação</h5>
            <select name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_tributacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_tributacao))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Atividade</h5>
            <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_atividade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_atividade))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"];?>"> 
              <?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"]; ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Status</h5>
            <select name="status" id="status" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_status))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <h5>Pesquisar</h5>
           <input name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Enviar">
           
          </div>
                    
         </div>
        </div>              
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div> 
    
   </div>   
      

      
   <div class="row">
    
    <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE O RESULTADO DA PESQUISA DO FORMULÁRIO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="resultado-pesquisa">
          
     
     <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE AS INFORMAÇÕES DE RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
     
     <div class="col-lg-12" id="exibicao">
      
      <!-- TABELA QUE EXIBE DINAMICAMENTE COM O PHP OS RESULTADOS DA CONSULTA AO BANCO -->
      
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="resultado-exibicao">
       
       <thead>
        <tr><th>Código</th><th>COD</th><th>EMPRESA</th><th>TRIBUTAÇÃO</th><th>TIPO DE ATIVIDADE</th><th>DT.VENC</th><th>DT.INÍCIO</th><th>DT.FIM</th><th>STATUS</th><!--<th>DETALHES</th>--></tr>
       </thead>
       
       <tbody id="registros-atividades">
        
        
        
       </tbody>
       
       
      
      </table>
            
      
     </div>
     
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- DIV PARA EXIBIÇÃO DO RETORNO DA CONSULTA DOS CAMPOS DETALHES E FEEDBACK -->
   
   <div class="row" id="detalhesfeedback">
    
    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO DETALHES COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 panel panel-primary" id="detalhes">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">OBSERVAÇÕES</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body" id="espaco-detalhes">
      
     </div>
           
    </div>
    

    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO FEEDBACK COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 panel panel-primary" id="feedback">
     
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">FEEDBACK DA GERÊNCIA / RESPONSÁVEL SETOR</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body" id="espaco-feedback">
      
     
      
     </div>
           
    </div>
    
    <!-- DIV COM OS BOTÕES QUE EXECUTAM AÇÕES NO BANCO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="botoes-detalhes-feedback">
        
     <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" href="#" >Inserir Observações</a></button>
     <a class="btn btn-md btn-success" href="#" >Reabrir Atividades</a></button>
     <!--<button class="btn btn-md btn-danger"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-reabrir-atividades">Sem Movimento/Arquivo</a></button>-->
     
    </div>
    
    <!--
    
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modal-autorizar">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close"
          aria-label="close"
          data-dismiss="modal">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Você tem certeza que quer realizar esse procedimento ?</h4>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal-body">
               
        <a class="btn btn-lg" value="confirmar" name="confirmar" id="confirmar" style="background-color:CornflowerBlue; color: white; font-weight: bold">ALTERANDO O STATUS DA ATIVIDADE</a> <!-- &nbsp <a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" value="NAO" name="nao" id="negar">NAO</a> 
      
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   
    -->
    
   </div>
   
   
   
  </div>
  
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  
  
  <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
  <script src="_bootstrap4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="_scripts/interface-script.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
 
  
</body> <!-- FIM DO BODY -->
</html> <!-- FIM DO HTML -->

<?php
 // Fechando Conexão
 
 mysqli_close($conecta);
 
 
?>

<!-- ARQUIVO PHP QUE REALIZA O SELECT NO BANCO DE DADOS interface-resultado-pesquisa.php -->

<?php 
 
 
 require_once("conexao-com-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO

 
  
 // CONSULTA GERAL DO BANCO  QUE RETORNA O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA DA PÁGINA INTERFACE.PHP 
  
 session_start(); 
 
   
   //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
   
   $pegaropcao   = utf8_decode($_POST["prioridade"]);
   $tipodedata = $_POST["data"];
   $dataInicial = $_POST["dataInicial"];
   $dataFinal  = $_POST["dataFinal"];
   $cod = utf8_decode($_POST["cod"]);
   $empresas   = utf8_decode($_POST["empresas"]);
   $tributacao = utf8_decode($_POST["tributacao"]);
   $atividade  = utf8_decode($_POST["atividade"]);
   
   $status = utf8_decode($_POST["status"]);
   $responsavel = $_SESSION["nome"];
   
   
   
   //VERIFICA QUAL É O TIPO DE ATIVIDADE ENTRE AS EXTRAS, URGENTES OU COMUM
     
   if($pegaropcao == "Comum")
   {
    $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'C'";
   
   }
   else if($pegaropcao == "Urgente")
   {
    $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'U'";
   
   } 
   else if($pegaropcao == "Extra")
   {
    $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'E'";
   
   } 
   else 
   {
    $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  <> 'N'";
   
   } 
   
   
   //IF PARA VERIFICAR POR QUAL TIPO DE DATA O BANCO IRÁ FILTRAR 
      
   if (isset($dataInicial) AND isset($dataFinal)) 
   {
    $teste = "Entrou no IF";
       
    if($tipodedata == "vencimento")
    {
     $variavel = " AND DT_VENCIMENTO BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal' ORDER BY DT_VENCIMENTO"; 
    }
    else if ($tipodedata == "finalizacao")
    {
     $variavel = " AND DT_FIM BETWEEN  '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal' ORDER BY DT_FIM";
    }
    else if($tipodedata == "inicio")
    {
     $variavel = " AND DT_INICIO BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal' ORDER BY DT_INICIO";
    }
    
   }
   //(ESSE ELSE QUE É A PARTE DO ERRO) -------------------------AQUI---------------------------------
   else  
   {  
    
    $variavel = " ORDER BY DT_VENCIMENTO asc";
   }   
   
  
   
   //REALIZA A CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DO FORMULÁRIO
   
   $pesquisar    = "SELECT COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO, TIPO_ATIVIDADE, STATUS, DETALHES, FEEDBACK, DATE_FORMAT(DT_VENCIMENTO, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS DT_VENCIMENTO, DATE_FORMAT(DT_INICIO, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS DT_INICIO, DATE_FORMAT(DT_FIM, '%d/%m/%Y') AS DT_FIM, codigo FROM tbl_atividades";
   $pesquisar    .= " WHERE COD like '%$cod%' AND EMPRESAS like '%$empresas' AND TRIBUTACAO like '%$tributacao' AND TIPO_ATIVIDADE like '%$atividade' AND RESPONSAVEL = '$responsavel' AND STATUS like '%$status' $tipodeatividade $variavel";
          
   $operacao_consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, $pesquisar) or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); 
   
   
   
    $retorno = array();
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($operacao_consulta))
    {     
      $retorno[] = $linha;  
    }  
    
   
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    
     
  
?>
```

VEJA ABAIXO A IMAGEM DO ERRO QUE DÁ NO ARQUIVO PHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe na segunda imagem que tem uma parte marcada em vermelha no qual é a saída do valor da variável que foi configurada dentro do ELSE.

ABAIXO, A IMAGEM COM O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA, NO QUAL EXECUTA O IF, QUE UTILIZADA OS $_POST QUE VOCÊS ESTÃO DIZENDO NÃO ESTAR RECEBENDO VALORES.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faz um `var_dump($pesquisar);` e verifica como que o seu select fica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme dizem **todos os erros no seu script**, os **índices não estão definidos**.

Repare que todas as linhas que apresentam erros estão relacionadas ao `$_POST`:

[image: print]

O que você precisa fazer é conferir os atributos `name` dos `input` do seu formulário e conferir o método, se está definido como `post`.

O serviço do `if` mencionado é justamente verificar se sua página recebeu as informações:

```
if (isset($dataInicial) AND isset($dataFinal))
```

E é justamente aqui a raiz do problema! A função `isset()` do PHP retorna `true` até mesmo nos casos em que a variável esteja vazia: `$foo = ''`. Que é justamente o que está acontecendo no seu formulário!

Uma das soluções é trocar o `isset()` por `empty()`. Relacionando diretamente ao seu código, podemos fazer assim:

```
$dataInicial = !empty($_POST["dataInicial"]) ? $_POST["dataInicial"] : null;
$dataFinal  = !empty($_POST["dataFinal"]) ? $_POST["dataFinal"] : null;
```

Com o estado `null` nessas variáveis, o seu `if` vai funcionar como esperado, já que o `isset()` retorna `false` caso a variável esteja `null`.

---

Veja uma forma simples de **conferir o que e qual método está vindo do formulário**:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Informações via método POST:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($_POST);
echo 'Informações via método GET:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: $_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php)
>
> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)
>
> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: empty()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Comment: Sim, entendi brother. Porém os dados que vem do POST estão sim sendo recebidos. Até a condição do IF é executada e essa condição do IF utiliza os mesmos dados que vem do POST. EU vou atualizar o código que postei aqui, com o código em HTML e javaScript utilizado.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Não. Não estão sendo recebidos! Se estivessem sido recebidas, o PHP não iria acusar índice não definido. Repare que adicionei um pequeno script pra vc conferir o que está recebendo na sua página.

Comment: Editei o código para vocês visualizarem melhor. LilESprY, então como a condição do IF é executada e a query me retorna o resultado da consulta ?

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson tem algumas informações de contato no meu perfil. Chama em qualquer uma delas que vou te ajudar com seu código. Infelizmente, do jeito que está na pergunta não dá pra reproduzir...

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia.

O único erro que vi no seu código foi não tratar os $_POST. Ele sempre vai manter esse erro se você não enviar nenhum post.
O que pode ser feito são essas condições:

```
$pegaropcao   = (isset($_POST["prioridade"]) && $_POST["prioridade"] != "") ? utf8_decode($_POST["prioridade"]) : "";
    $tipodedata = (isset($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] != "") ?  $_POST["data"] : "";
    $dataInicial = (isset($_POST["dataInicial"]) && $_POST["dataInicial"] != "") ?  $_POST["dataInicial"] : "";
    $dataFinal  = (isset($_POST["dataFinal"]) && $_POST["dataFinal"] != "") ?  $_POST["dataFinal"] : "";
    $cod = (isset($_POST["cod"]) && $_POST["cod"] != "") ?  utf8_decode($_POST["cod"]) : "";
    $empresas   = (isset($_POST["empresas"]) && $_POST["empresas"] != "") ?  utf8_decode($_POST["empresas"]) : "";
    $tributacao = (isset($_POST["tributacao"]) && $_POST["tributacao"] != "") ?  utf8_decode($_POST["tributacao"]) : "";
    $atividade  = (isset($_POST["atividade"]) && $_POST["atividade"] != "") ?  utf8_decode($_POST["atividade"]) : "";

    $status = (isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"] != "") ?  utf8_decode($_POST["status"]) : "";
    $responsavel = (isset($_SESSION["nome"]) && $_SESSION["nome"] != "") ?  $_SESSION["nome"] : "";
```

O que eu fiz foi verificar se os $_POST existe, se não existir retorna vazio.

Comment: Se você realmente leu o código todo dele você deve ter percebido que se não vier nenhum dado no post entra em um else. Então com isso não vai empurrar nada, só solucionar os erros caso não venha nada pelo post. E o utf8_decode() faz parte do código dele tbm, se existir valor ele da esse comando (Não sei qual valor vem então mantive o que ele mesmo fez).

Comment: "*- se não vier nenhum dado no post entra em um else*" então da linha `85` pra baixo não importa, também, se veio dados ou não?! Vai montar uma query cheia de `like '%'`... Aliás, não me entenda mal! Só dei um toque porque achei que seria útil. Desculpe!

Comment: Sem delongas, mas olhando o meu código completo, ao invés de teorias, sem ofensas, mas vocês poderiam apontar onde consta meu erro ? Seja no PHP, na query MySQL, no HTML no JavaScript ... Por favor. Humildemente falando.

Comment: Editei a postagem e adicionei uma imagem na qual prova que os $_POST estão chegando sim no arquivo PHP

Comment: Você chegou a testar colocando esse código que fiz no lugar do seu?

Comment: Se não vier dados no POST naquelas duas variáveis citadas, LipESprY, realmente não importa. Ai realiza o ELSE.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson tá. Mas e o restante? Na linha 85 vc precisa dos outros dados, que **também estão acusando erro de índice**. Como disse ali em cima, vai ficar uma query toda bugada! A pesar de tudo, tá muito difícil entender todo esse seu código. Você misturou o arquivo no snipper e tá me deixando um tanto confuso.

Comment: @LucasXavier, coloquei seu código e continua dando o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @LipESprY, Você chegou a ver a última imagem que coloquei lá ? Aquilo é o retorno da consulta quando a condição IF é executada e não é preciso entrar no ELSE. Essa condição IF é executada utilizando valores que vieram via $_POST. Se, como você diz, o $_POST não está chegando, como então a query é executada utilizando tais valores vindo do $_POST ?

Comment: @LipESprY e LucasXavier, eu sei que o código está com algum erro, por isso postei aqui. Só que minha esperando era as pessoas analizarem o código e verem onde está o erro. Deixei disponível a parte PHP, HTML e JavaScript. O erro está em algum desses lugares. Creio eu que seja no PHP.

Comment: @LucasXavier, mas já melhorou. Agora só está apresentando um erro dizendo que a variável não está definida.  Notice: Undefined variable: variavel in C:\wamp64\www\projeto-do-sistema-interno-jca\interface-resultado-pesquisa.php on line 84

Comment: Retira o else que fica abaixo do comentário: `(ESSE ELSE QUE É A PARTE DO ERRO) ` e cola somente essa linha: `$variavel = " ORDER BY DT_VENCIMENTO asc";` abaixo do comentario: `IF PARA VERIFICAR POR QUAL TIPO DE DATA O BANCO IRÁ FILTRAR `